# porting 32 bit OSX app to 64 bit

Tags: macos, cocoa, 64-bit

I am interested in an open source project that is only available
for 32 bit builds. To get 64 bit build, there is a commercial extension.

I am thinking of porting it myself. It is a large medical imaging app.
What kind of issus should I be aware of when attempting this? On windows+C#,
it is quite easy to recompile for 64 bit. But, this is C++ and Cocoa.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: this is the project:  http://www.osirix-viewer.com/ .

Source on github:  https://github.com/pixmeo/osirix

Comment: Did you try it?  Did you run into any problems?  We can help you with specific questions if you have them.

Comment: I am trying to decide if it is worth it; have not tried it yet. Seeking advice.

Comment: It's definitely worth it. 32 bit apps will not be supported forever, and lack many many modern features.

Comment: If it's an open source project, can you specify which one so we could take a look at it? How easy it is to port can depend on a huge number of factors including whether it relies on Carbon-UI components (which aren't available in 64-bit), and also what assumptions it makes about the size of types.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple's 64-Bit Transition Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/intro/intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001064-CH205-TPXREF101)

Comment: also, the Cocoa 64-bit Transition Guide at: <http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247>